# Создание образа docker для удаленной машины

Tags: golang, docker, visual-studio-code

Есть установленная среда `Visula Studio Code` под `Windows` на одной машине. На ней веду разработку на `GoLang`. И есть другая вирт. машина под `Linux` с установленным `Docker`- ом.  Как мне создать `docker` образ чтобы я его мог запустить на вирт . машине? Сам `docker` установить на машину с `Windows` не представляется возможным.

Comment: Сделать сборку docker-образа в каком-либо месте. Например, я делаю пипелину по сборке в GitLab. Другие сервисы также предлагают сделать, тот же Docker Hub, GitHub Actions, GitLab CI/CD, Travis CI.

Comment: @TotalPusher т.е я свой проект вместе с exe заливаю на gitlab , потом на машине с Linux и Docker  выкачиваю с репозитория и создаю образ ?

Comment: Примерный путь такой: 1. в репозитории хранится исходный код приложения плюс скрипты для сборки (`.gitlab-ci.yml` для GitLab). 2. (опционально) когда в репозиторий приходит мерж-реквест (МР) (или пул-реквест), запускаются скрипты автотестов. 3. когда в ветку мержится МР, запускается задача сбора нового docker-образа и размещением его в репозитории (частном, либо Docker Hub). На этом шаге происходит `docker build ...`, `docker push ...`. Команды билдежки прописываются в Dockerfile обычно. https://akyriako.medium.com/build-golang-docker-images-with-gitlab-ci-pipelines-2117f8505350

Comment: `вместе с exe заливаю на gitlab`. Вообще исполняемый файл как раз должен билдиться и сохраняться в образ в команде сборки образа. Но мне не понятно, почему `exe`? Или вы делаете образ только под windows? Если да, то `exe` скорее всего не получится собрать на Linux машине, и тогда да, придется его сохранять прямо в репозитории, а в задаче сборке образа просто копировать, причем где будет сборка - там тоже должен быть windows...